# Sub-totals for each column combination in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I currently have a sample dataframe as such below

| date | subject | animal | colors | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | English | cat | blue | 1 |
| Feb | Chemistry | dog | green | 2 |

And assuming that the values above are the only unique values for each of the columns

I am having difficulties trying to create a new multi-level header dataframe using pivot where aggfunc=median and also includes the "sub-total" for each column combination, where "sub-total" refers to when all categories of that column would be included for the aggregation.

For example, i am hoping the resulting dataframe would look like this below, where 'all' refers to the grouping of all the categories for that particular column.

| subject | english | english | english | english | english | english | english | english | english | repeat the 9 columns for 'Chemistry' | all | repeat the remaining 8 columns for 'all' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **animal** | **cat** | **cat** | **cat** | dog | dog | dog | all | all | all |  | cat |  |
| **colors** | **blue** | **green** | **all** | blue | green | all | blue | green | all |  | blue |  |
| **date** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Jan** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Feb** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Following this, there should be a 27 columns because:

- number of unique subjects + 1 subtotal = 3
- number of unique animals + 1 subtotal = 3
- number of unique colors + 1 subtotal = 3

3 x 3 x 3 = 27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can convert your columns as `Categorical` before `pivot`:

```
from itertools import combinations

# Transform discrete columns as categorical features
cols = ['date', 'subject', 'animal', 'colors']
cats = {col: pd.CategoricalDtype(list(df[col].unique()) + ['all'], ordered=True)
           for col in cols}
df = df.astype(cats)

# Compute intermediate subtotals
data = []
for grp in combinations(cols, r=len(cols)-1):
    df1 = df.groupby(list(grp), as_index=False, observed=True)['value'].sum()
    data.append(df1)
out = pd.concat([df, *data]).fillna('all')

# Reshape your dataframe to get all combinations
out = out.pivot_table(index='date', columns=['subject', 'animal', 'colors'], 
                      values='value', fill_value=-1, aggfunc='sum', observed=False)
```

Bonus: now you also have the column subtotal:

```
>>> out
subject English                                         Chemistry                                          all                                        
animal      cat            dog            all                 cat            dog            all            cat            dog            all          
colors     blue green all blue green all blue green all      blue green all blue green all blue green all blue green all blue green all blue green all
date                                                                                                                                                  
Jan           1     0   1    0     0   0    1     0   0         0     0   0    0     0   0    0     0   0    1     0   0    0     0   0    0     0   0
Feb           0     0   0    0     0   0    0     0   0         0     0   0    0     2   2    0     2   0    0     0   0    0     2   0    0     0   0
all           1     0   0    0     0   0    0     0   0         0     0   0    0     2   0    0     0   0    0     0   0    0     0   0    0     0   0
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This is very close to what I needed, just that when I amended all instances of "sum" to "median", several columns disappeared. Is there a way to keep the same formatting, but all values in the table should be giving the "median" instead of "sum"?

Comment: nevermind, found out I just needed to include a dropna=False as an argument in the pivot_table() function. Thank you for your help!